# How can I break concentration besides damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The *[Invulnerability](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/invulnerability)* spell, from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, makes you immune to *all* damage.

With the most obvious way out of the picture, how can I stop your concentration if I don't have Sleet Storm prepared?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### The Sleep spell might work

If you are asleep, you are unconscious.  If you are unconscious, you are incapacitated. (Conditions, App. A, PHB, p. 292).  If you are incapacitated, you cannot concentrate.

> • **Being incapacitated or killed**. You lose concentration on a spell if you are incapacitated or if you die. (Basic Rules, p. 80/PHB. p. 203)

The trick is to push/shove/drag the creature away from any other creature (20' or more away) if it is near other creatures (including your party), and then cast *sleep* at as high a level as one can.

1. One way to do that is cast a bunch of Eldritch Blasts with the
   Repelling Blast invocation, that hit (no damage, but target shoved or 
   moved for each blast that hits).
2. Have your Barbarian grapple, Shove/drag/pull the target, and hope that the Barbarian has more HP than the target.

   At that point, cast *sleep* at as high a level as one can.  Roll 5d8, and an additional 2d8 for every spell level expended above 1. Let's use a 5th level sleep to illustrate.

   Roll 5d8 + 8d8 = 13d8 which is an average of 58.5 HP. (At 7th level, 76.5).

Depending on how you roll and how much damage the target had already taken before it put up invulnerability, problem solved.  If not, it was worth a try.

1. The usual caveat about not being able to put to sleep undead, or
   creatures immune to that condition, applies.
2. The reason that I made the estimate that the target needs to have
   already taken some damage is that this is a 9th level spell, so the
   HP of whomever is casting it is presumed to be substantial.

#### At higher levels, Power Word Stun

If you have access to 8th level spells, a successful Power Word Stun will incapacitate a creature.  That solves the problem.

#### Paralysis / poison, or using a magic item, etc

Depending upon what you have available to you, anything that can inflict the paralyzed condition incapacitates the target.  Various poisons can incapacitate or poison a target: Torpor(incapacitates), Essence of Ether (renders unconscious), Oil of Taggit (renders unconscious, Crawler Mucus (paralyzed).  A Wand of paralysis will, if the Con save is missed, achieve that aim.

#### Get a Monk Involved

Even though the attack will do 0 damage, a monk attacking with *Stunning Strike* will stun the target. Once stunned it is incapacitated and Bob's your uncle.

PHB p. 79 (Stunning Strike)

> When you hit another creature with a melee weapon attack, you can
>   spend 1 ki point to attempt a stunning strike.  The target must
>   succeed on a Constitution saving throw, or be stunned until the end of
>   your next turn.

---

I am pretty sure that a Sorcerer's Empower metamagic won't allow the HP amount to be boosted when casting the sleep spell (by re-rolling low numbers), [so I asked a question about that](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/116690/22566).

Answer (score 21):

[Concentration](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Spells#content)

> The following factors can break concentration:
>
> **Casting another spell that requires concentration**. You lose concentration on a spell if you cast another spell that requires concentration. You can’t concentrate on two spells at once.
>
> ...
>
> **Being Incapacitated or killed**. You lose concentration on a spell if you are Incapacitated or if you die.
>
> **The GM might also decide that certain environmental phenomena, such as a wave crashing over you while you’re on a storm--tossed ship, require you to succeed on a DC 10 Constitution saving throw to maintain concentration on a spell.**

- A swarm of flies buzzing around the disgusting smelly corpses that fill the room you're in? Can cause a concentration check.
- In a desert during combat a sand storm occurs? Can cause a concentration check.
- You're running after a thief in a large city with hundreds of people moving, pushing each other and merchants shouting at the bazaar? Can cause a concentration check.
- The party tries to negotiate with a slaver sheikh in his harem while lusty concubines try to caress, undress you? Definitely causes a concentration check. Especially bad situation if a cleric used Enhance Ability to gain CHA roll advantage and loses it, making it less likely to explain the situation with success.

*(All examples actually happened in games I took part in)*

I do advise against constantly forcing concentration checks on a player, but the environmental option can easily flavor a session to place emphasis on certain aspects of a place or situation, and the DC 10 saving throw is a low enough danger to include such scenes or events once or twice per session.

Being grappled could also cause concentration checks happen, even if damage isn't caused by initial grappling attack, or at least when the grappled spellcaster is pushed/thrown off somewhere.

Answer (score 13):

**[Earthquake](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Earthquake#content)** can do the job, albeit on a rather larger than single-target scale.

> You create a seismic disturbance at a point on the ground that you can see within range. For the Duration, an intense tremor rips through the ground in a 100-foot- radius circle centered on that point and shakes creatures and structures in contact with the ground in that area.
>
> The ground in the area becomes difficult terrain. **Each creature on the ground that is concentrating must make a Constitution saving throw. On a failed save, the creature's Concentration is broken.**
>
> ...

Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 10):

## You can incapacitate the target

Here's the relevant text, found on PHB pg. 203:

> The following factors can break concentration:
>
> Casting another spell that requires concentration...
>
> [...] Whenever you take damage while you are concentrating on a spell, you must make a Constitution saving throw to maintain your concentration. The DC equals 10 or half the damage you take, whichever number is higher
>
> [...] You lose concentration on a spell if you are incapacitated or if you die.

Beyond incapacitating the target or killing them outright (such as via power word kill), the only option for damaging the creature before the duration expires is to use Dispel Magic (9th level to guarantee).

Comment: @Lino I'll edit to clarify

Comment: Sleep spells...

Answer (score 10):

### A Useful **Suggestion**

As has been stated elsewhere, incapacitating the target (via sleep or some other method) or casting Dispell Magic are the most reliable methods. But if these options are unavailable, or unlikely to work, there is another surefire way to end concentration:

> - **Casting another spell that requires concentration.** You lose
>     concentration on a spell if you cast another spell that requires
>     concentration. You can’t concentrate on two spells at once. (PHB, p. 203)

If the target is not immune to being Charmed, you could cast the second level spell Suggestion, and cause them to cast another concentration spell. Note that this depends on your ability to word the suggestion in a way that sounds reasonable.

You could suggest an offense concentration spell, (like delayed blast fireball), convincing the target that offense is more important than defense. Or, if you don't know what spells the target can cast, you could suggest that they use the Ready action to Ready an offensive spell against the next enemy that tries to attack, since readying any spell requires concentration (PHB p. 193).

**EDIT**: Praxiteles also suggested the excellent option of casting Tasha's Hideous Laughter. Since both Suggestion and Tasha's Hideous Laughter require a failed Wisdom saving throw (and both spells have the same range, require you to see your target, and are concentration spells), and Tasha's Hideous Laughter incapacitates its target, Tasha's Hideous Laughter is probably a better choice.

Comment: If you succeeded in Charming the target, I expect you can simply suggest they stop concentrating on the Invulnerability spell ("it's unnecessary and tiring; we're all friends here").  This should work without requiring them to have alternative concentration spells to cast, or Readying an attack against you(!).

Comment: I highly doubt such a suggestion would be deemed "reasonable" by a DM, but feel free to attempt it.

Answer (score 4):

## Use Spells to invoke the condition incapacitated

Per the PHB p. 203:

> You lose concentration on a spell if you are *incapacitated* or if you die.

- **Tasha’s Hideous Laughter:** (Level 1)

  > “The target must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw of fall prone, becoming *Incapacitated*”
- **Command:** (Level 1) Command an opponent to **“Sleep”** with effects as above. (Also consider the command **“Daydream”** mentioned below.)

  > “You speak a one-word command to a creature you can see within range. The target must succeed on a Wisdom saving throw or follow the command on its next turn.“
- **Sleep:** (Level 1)

  > “Starting with the creature that has the lowest current hit points, each creature affected by this spell falls Unconscious.” Unconcious creatures are incapacitated.
- **Eyebite: Asleep** (Level 6)

  > “The target falls unconscious.”
- **Symbol: Pain** (Level 7)

  > “Each target must make a Constitution saving throw and becomes incapacitated with excruciating pain for 1 minute on a failed save.”
- **Imprisonment: Slumber** (Level 9)

  > ”The target falls asleep and can't be awoken.”

## Use Spells to break *concentration*

RAW may be challenging to pin down a precise reading on these, but RAI may be in support.

- **Command: “Daydream”** (Level 1) By definition daydreaming is a state of non-concentration (“a series of pleasant thoughts that distract one's attention from the present.“) Commands like “unconcentrate” probably aren’t precise enough.
- **Phantasmal Force:** (Level 2)

  > “While a target is affected by the spell, the target *treats the phantasm as if it were real*...An affected target is so convinced of the phantasm’s reality that it can even take damage from the illusion.”

This may be more tenuous. Even though the wizard isn’t taking damage - he or she will treat the phantasm as *if it were real* (i.e. as if it were taking damage) - thus invoking a Concentration check. One might counter argue that the wizard would rationalize it cannot take damage from the illusion, even if real, so cannot be distracted. If there are ever spells that are exceptions to invulnerability - this option might have a stronger argument.

- **Confusion:** (Level 4)

  > “This spell assaults and twists creatures' minds, spawning delusions and provoking uncontrolled action.”

This would take a ruling whether one can hold one’s concentration as one’s mind is twisted, assaulted and having delusions: a reasonable call for a Concentration check.

## Use “abnormal” movement to break concentration...

The PHB p. 203 states:

> *Normal* activity, such as moving and attacking, doesn't interfere with concentration.

This suggests “abnormal” activity may disrupt concentration. As above this may take some creative RAI and may be DM dependent. Consider spells like:

- **Thunderwave:** (Level 1) Being thrown backwards from a concussive wave is probably not a normal activity for many.
- **Confusion:** (Level 4)

  > “This spell assaults and twists creatures' minds, spawning delusions and provoking *uncontrolled action.*”

Uncontrolled action is by definition abnormal movement.

- **Irresistable Dance:** (Level 6) Dancing irresistably may be considered abnormal movement, though knowing our players, maybe not all of them.
- **Earthquake:** (Level 8)

  > The ground in the area becomes difficult terrain. Each creature on the ground that is concentrating must make a Constitution saving throw. On a failed save, the *creature's Concentration is broken.*

Earthquake is the most explicit in this involuntary movement group and may suggest to some that breaking Concentration must be described in the spell for a save to be invoked.

Comment: I think you may be stretching in assuming that "normal doesn't" implies "abnormal does", and am not sure that Command would work as you suggest (for example, I don't think a target can voluntarily fall asleep in 6 seconds), but I'm upvoting your answer anyway because of the excellent idea of using Tasha's Hideous Laughter.

Comment: "...though knowing our players, maybe not all of them" made my day.